Why is the Archimedean spiral called the Archimedean spiral?
I wonder why it is called the Archimedean spiral even though it was first studied by Conon of Samos.
Is it because Archimedes produced much more meaningful results than Conon?

Nothing can be said with certainty about very old ideas. Who claims that Conon of Samos discovered it? Wolfram's page says so without any evidence. Recall the so-called Stigler's Law of Eponymy? It states "states that no scientific discovery is ever named after its original discoverer..."

"Archimedes described such a spiral in his book On Spirals. Conon of Samos was a friend of his and Pappus states that this spiral was discovered by Conon." Archimedes' treatise On Spirals: survived.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285627/how-are-constants-functions-named-after-their-discoverer/285644#285644
